# s3 amazon Metadata Content-Type

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();

        metadata.setContentEncoding("gzip");
        metadata.setContentType("application/x-gzip");
        metadata.addUserMetadata("Expires","3600");
        metadata.addUserMetadata("Cache-Control","public");
        metadata.addUserMetadata("max-age","432000");
```

i am getting key in s3 as "x-amz-meta-max-age","x-amz-meta-expires". Its adding 
"x-amz-" in front please help but setContentEncoding,setContentType is working fine but for rest 3 getting "x-amz-" in front please help

Answer (score 0):

You can set:

```
metadata.setExpirationTime("Thu, 21 Mar 2042 08:16:32 GMT");
metadata.setCacheControl("public");
```

For more information: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html